# Date and time comparision

Tags: php, date, time

guys i am new to pp what i am trying to do is fetching date and time from db and comparing to the current date if its fallen within then execute"this" else"this" i don't know whats going wrong.. thanks in advance

```
<?php 
$today = new Date Time('now', new Date Time Zone('Asia/Katakana'));
$today->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');           
$end= $row["end_date"];
if($end>$today){                  
$confirm=$row["confirm"];
$status = $row["status"];
if($confirm==$status){ ?>
```

i am new to stack over flow also and its not allowing me to post question with error.there is no space or error in writing in my real code

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
$end= $row["end_date"]; 
//converted your end date into timestamp through strtotime($end)
if(strtotime($end) > strtotime("now")) { 
  $confirm=$row["confirm"]; 
  $status = $row["status"]; 
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the `$end` a `Date Time` object and your condition will be fine.

Here you compare a `Date Time` object with a string. That's why this is not working.

```
$end = new Date Time($row["end_date"], new Date Time Zone('Asia/Katakana'));
```

A code like above.

Answer (score 0):

What about to use strtotime. try this:

```
strtotime($time);
time() - strtotime($var);
```

and convert it by this:

```
 if((time()-(60*60*24)) < strtotime($var))
 { 
   do this;
 }
 else{
   do that;
 }`
```